# Join multiple databases mysql

Tags: mysql

I have roughly 2 Million records in two different databases, each has 1 million. I want to join the two tables with each other to find the differences but due to the data size the mysql throws a time-out error each time i perform the action. This is my query:

```
SELECT id FROM db1.table1 AS a INNER JOIN db2.table1 AS b ON ( b.Id != a.Id )
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MySQL subquery:

```
SELECT id FROM db1.table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM db2.table1);
```

The above query consists of two parts. The first part which is inside parenthesis selects field id from db2.table1 without any limitation. This result will be used in the outer one to remove unwanted records from db1.table1.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped. A short and nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are joining each db1 record with all db2 records that have another ID. So thats about a trillion rows generated.

Try the following instead:

```
select * from db1.table1 where id not in (select id from db2.table1);
```

and

```
select * from db2.table1 where id not in (select id from db1.table1);
```

or combined:

```
select 'db1' as db, * from db1.table1 where id not in (select id from db2.table1)
union all
select 'db2' as db, * from db2.table1 where id not in (select id from db1.table1);
```

Comment: The ids are exactly the same but there is only some rows which doesn't exist in the second table

Comment: Yes, but say you have a record in db1 with ID = 1 and you join by `b.Id != a.Id`. Then you join with all records in db2 except for the one record with ID = 1. This is about one million rows for the first record alone. Then another million for the second ID and so on.